# Changing the property sheet background color as same as parent dialog

Tags: c++, mfc

I created a property sheet inside dialog. But the property sheet is appearing in white background color by default. I want the property sheet in same background color as the dialog on which it is placed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement the message event `OnEraseBkgnd` an your `CPropertyPage`

```
class CMyPage : public CPropertyPage
{
public:

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()

    afx_msg BOOL OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC);    
}
```

Add the application framework message event to your message loop:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyPage, CPropertyPage)
      ON_WM_ERASEBKGND()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Finally implement the message event method. The implementation of the method makes use of
[`GetSysColor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724371%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), [`CDC::FillSolidRect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa293783(v=vs.60).aspx)
and [`CDC::GetClipBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa293831%28v=vs.60%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
BOOL CMyPage::OnEraseBkgnd( CDC *pDC ) 
{
    // get the background color
    COLORREF bkCol = ::GetSysColor(COLOR_MENU);

    // get the area you have to fill
    CRect rect;
    pDC->GetClipBox(&rect); 

    // fill the rectangular area with the color
    pdC->FillSolidRect(&rect, bkCol);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is covered on the internet already from what I can see.

For example:

http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?235997-CPropertySheet-color

To change the background color of a window you can use `CWnd::OnEraseBkgnd()`. You can use the passed `CDC` object to paint the background to any color.